# How to change the Map Units in Grass?

Tags: grass-gis, units

because v.segment measures all offsets in map units, i have to change it. (I want to put all of 50 meters a point)

So I checked g.proj -p:
-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------

unit       : degree
units      : degrees
meters     : 1.0

Now I dont know how to change and how that affects my previous work. Can I open the PROJ_UNITS in my Databasefolder and change it manual (e.g. unit: meterunits: metersmeters: 1.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the principles of GRASS GIS: a LOCATION = one projection (an only one an no "reprojection on the fly" as QGIS, for example)

- [Projections and spatial transformations in GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/projectionintro.html)
- [GRASS GIS: Map Reprojection](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Map_Reprojection)

> Reprojecting data in GRASS GIS

```
1) first create an location in the source projection/geodetic datum (using the GRASS Location Wizard d you can generate the location from the dataset itself)
2) import the map/image into the location,
3) create a second destination location in the projection/geodetic datum you want to reproject the map/image into,
4) Within the destination location session, use r.proj or v.proj (depending on whether the map/image is raster or vector) to reproject the map/image from the import location to the destination location.
```

Therefore, you need to:

1. create a new location with map units projection in meters
2. use [v.proj](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.proj.html) to reproject your vector layer from the original location (units in degrees) to the new location (units in meters)

Comment: Thank you for feedback. You have it addressed: I was confused because it's just so changeable in qgis. I will try it.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I created a second location (UTM). If I want to use the new created Segmentpoints (created in new UTM location) in my "Standard-Location (Lat/Long) so I have to do a second time v.proj to get them back right?

Comment: yes,  each time you want to reproject a layer.